# PHP Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Tags: php

Есть такой PHP код:

```
$totaldead_alldef[1] = $dead['1']+$dead['2']+$dead['3']+$dead['4']+$dead['5']+$dead['6']+$dead['7']+$dead['8']+$dead['9']+$dead['10'];
```

Он вызывает такой Warning:

**Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 1551**

Что обозначает данный Warning? Почему так происходит? Как от него избавиться?

Comment: а что такое `$dead`?

Comment: Читайте текст ошибки. Через некоторое время не потребуется обращаться даже к гуглу - причина ошибки (пусть и не всегда она будет явно находится в коде) всегда описана в тексте, и по этой ошибке становится ясно, что какая-то переменная, массивом не являющаяся, используется, как массив. Скорее всего у вас не объявлен заранее $totaldead_alldef как массив, что позволительно (в рамках PHP), но потенциально содержит ошибку (если встречается такой случай, то, возможно, кодер предполагает существование уже созданного и заполненного массива), поэтому выдается именно предупреждение.

Comment: $dead это переменная, которую я так понимаю нужно объявить как array()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас или $totaldead_alldef или $dead или обе переменные не объявлены как array()

Comment: А можно сделать так $dead = array(); ?

Comment: @eprivalov1 да, но в данном отрывке кода вы используете уже заполненный массив $dead, этого будет недостаточно.